# Doubleouble Talkalk

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

## Input

A non-empty string or list of capital letters `k` with length between 3 to 5000.

## Output

A value indicating whether `k` can be expressed as `a+b+b`, where `a` and `b` are non-empty.

## Truthy test cases

```
SSS
SNYYY
SNYY
SNNYY
SNYNY
```

## Falsy test cases

```
FALSYTESTCASES
FALSYFALSYTESTCASES
FALSYTESTCASESXFALSYTESTCASES
FALSYTESTCASESFALSYTESTCASES
SMARTIEATIE
```

## Neglegible cases:

```
XX
lowercase
123
ABC (repeated 2000 times)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Interesting challenge, but some test cases would be nice.

Comment: The challenge was editted to specify the length of the input, such that edgecases are omitted.

Comment: A test case with multiple solutions might be nice. `SNYYNYY`.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/239788/106959), almost duplicate.

Comment: @Adám Nonsense!

Comment: @Nick The second test case "SNYYY" has a="SNY", b="Y".

Comment: @justhalf oops. more caffeine required apparently. :-P

Comment: Suggested testcase: FALSYFALSYTESTCASES

Comment: Is it allowed to generate every possible string and check if the input equals one of it? It should work but it takes a extremely long time.

Comment: Similar, but not identical challenge https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189358/is-it-double-speak

Comment: Is it possible in linear time?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure, but I think it is not

Comment: @qwr Will build pmt use KMP algorithm from end to beginning work in linear time?

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 21 bytes

Takes a string and returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
s=>/.(.+)\1$/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k5fT0NPWzPGUEVfryS1uESjWPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoZScHCwkqYmF7qoX2RkJA5xrMK4xCP9MMQxVLk5@gRHhrgGhzg7Brticw2qgggS1RNUHuzrGBTi6eoIxEDZ/wA)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

A non-regex solution.

```javascript
s=>(g=i=>s[2*i]&&s.slice(-2*i)==(q=s.slice(-i))+q|g(-~i))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k4j3TbT1q442kgrM1ZNrVivOCczOVVDF8jVtLXVKLSFi2RqamoX1qRr6NYBWQkJ/5Pz84rzc1L1cvLTNdI0lIKDg5U0NbnQRf0iIyNxiGMVxiUe6YchjqHKzdEnODLENTjE2THYFZtrUBVEkKieoPJgX8egEE9XRyAGyv4HAA)

Comment: I'd be interested to see how much longer a non-regex solution is

Comment: @pxeger I've added a non-regex version. But there may be a shorter way.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 13 bytes

```
cP$h_*>h_>~ʃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYv1abbJASoZ8Vp2GfF2daeaIaI3_XMTM_MUbBVS8hW4FBQKihRUFNIUlBKTkpVQuIlJyPzkVEyRpESgWKISxNgFCyA0AA)

### Explanation

This uses the parser library.

`h_` parses any non-empty string, so we ask if there is a `h_` followed by `h_` and then we feed the output of the second `h_` into `ʃ`. Since `ʃ` parses any fixed string given as input, this means it parses whatever `h_` gave again.

`cP` takes the parser we built and turns it into a function which returns true when there is at least one parse which completely consumes the string.

### Reflection

This is such a simple challenge it's hard for this to get any better, but I have some thoughts:

- `(>~ʃ)` is a pretty common function. It attempts to parse the result of the last parse again. However unless I assigned it a 2 byte name it wouldn't make any savings in this particular case.
- `(h_*>)` might also be useful to have a shortcut for.

Answer (score 6):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
Jtđ=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6Fku9So5MtF1SnJRcDBVZcLNJKTg4WIlLKdgvMjISSoMpGB3pB6LdHH2CI0Ncg0OcHYNdgzEEIgjIY0gH-zoGhXi6OgKxEsQpAA)

```
Jtđ=
J       Split the input into a list of parts
 t      Remove the first part
  đ     Check that there are exactly two remaining parts
   =    Check that the two remaining parts are equal
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒHÐƤḊEƇ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields a non-empty list (truthy) if the input can be expressed as `a+b+b` or an empty list (falsey) otherwise.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJI/DE44tebijy/VY@3@dRw1zQopKSzIqHzXMBbLdEnOKU0Hsw@32WUC@gq2dApCnGfn/f7RScHCwkg6XglKwX2RkJJwFZSBYkX4QlpujT3BkiGtwiLNjsGswFqEIgiqwKAj2dQwK8XR1BGIgPxYA)**

#### How?

```
ŒHÐƤḊEƇ - Link: list of characters, S
  ÐƤ    - for suffixes of S:
ŒH      -   split into half (if odd length first half is longer)
    Ḋ   - dequeue (we don't want to test for a+a, only a+b+b)
      Ƈ - keep those for which:
     E  -   all equal?
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 8 bytes

```
.(.+)\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9PQ09bM8ZQ5f//4OBgrmC/yMhIMAkkIGSkXySXm6NPcGSIa3CIs2OwazAaNwKvLJpksK9jUIinqyMQAwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
f(_:_++b++b)|b>""=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NI94qXls7CYg0a5LslJRsDf/nJmbmKdgqpCkoBftF@kUq/QcA) with truthy, or

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NI94qXls7CYg0a5LslJRsDf/nJmbmKdgqpCkouTn6BEeGuAaHODsGuwaj8pT@AwA) with falsy test case.

Thanks for a byte saved by Wheat Wizard.

Comment: You should be able to do `b>""` instead of `b/=""` to save 1 byte.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this is valid since some potential cases like `SNYYNYY` produce multiple `1`s.

Comment: Since the difference is really between "Has some value(s)" and "No value", I'd believe this is fair enough for a truthy/falsy classification, regardless of what the values actually are.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 67 bytes

```c
n;f(char*s){n=strlen(++s);return~-n&&!bcmp(s-~n/2,s+n%2,n/2)|f(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYtNC4JAEIbv/goLlN1UAm8hHSQMgvLQeGipDrX5BTrIjtHB8q/bWrcODczDDO/7SC@XchgwyJgsLmpGvMMltapKkTkO8UCl7V1h76FtT66ybhh5Pc59lxy0fFdf/Jkx3XsNo2/ScaHnHNSXEhnvHkVZpSxPW9Id3qgS24xNLTKt2wmnLrmjO8oAYEAshPhQ40sRC2MdbkEkESSrECL4eQ9/058QduE@2USh3jc)

-1 byte from ceilingcat

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 45 bytes

```
S←≡(□↙)+1⊃⇡↯⧻.
∊:⊙□♭⊞(□⊐/⊂⇌⊂⊂.).⊐/⊂∵(□S⊐⇌)S⇌.
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__UyDihpAg4omhKOKWoeKGmSkrMeKKg-KHoeKGr-Knuy4KRiDihpAg4oiKOuKKmeKWoeKZreKKnijilqHiipAv4oqC4oeM4oqC4oqCLiku4oqQL-KKguKItSjilqFT4oqQ4oeMKVPih4wuCgpGICJTU1MiCkYgIlNOWVlZIgpGICJTTllZIgpGICJTTk5ZWSIKRiAiU05ZTlkiCgpGICJGQUxTWVRFU1RDQVNFUyIK)

Comment: 25 bytes: [this](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RiDihpAgL-KGpeKJoeKKkCgv4omN4oavMl_CrzHihpkp4oaYMi064pe_Mi7ih6HiioPip7vilqEKCkYgIlNTUyIKRiAiU05ZWVkiCkYgIlNOWVkiCkYgIlNOTllZIgpGICJTTllOWSIKCkYgIkZBTFNZVEVTVENBU0VTIgo=)

Comment: 22 bytes: [Pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RiDihpAg4oiKMeKJoeKKkCjiiY3iioPihpnihpjijIrDtzLip7su4oaYKeKHoeKnuy7ilqHihpgxCgpGICJTU1MiCkYgIlNOWVlZIgpGICJTTllZIgpGICJTTk5ZWSIKRiAiU05ZTlkiCgpGICJGQUxTWVRFU1RDQVNFUyIK)

Comment: 21 bytes: [Pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RiDihpAg4oiKMeKJoSjiiY3iioPihpnihpjijIrDtzLip7su4oaYKeKHoeKKg-Knu8Kk4oaYMQoKRiAiU1NTIgpGICJTTllZWSIKRiAiU05ZWSIKRiAiU05OWVkiCkYgIlNOWU5ZIgoKRiAiRkFMU1lURVNUQ0FTRVMiCg==)

Comment: Uiua changed, so those first two pads don't work anymore :)

Comment: They still work, it's just that they won't work later

Comment: No, they give wrong answers now. Because the behavior of `length box` was changed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
⊙ΦＥθ…⮌θκι⁼ι×²∕ι²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYg7CsMwEAWvonIFSqPWVXCSzmBMLiDkBS/Z6GsLfPq1/JiZ4vnNFR8di8yFwg7PcMKHeMcCk0uQjRpPzzhuMcGCDUtFyNqon@6h7jsfjiuQUV/6YwVr1IsarXhfVt8bREIMFTvyaHwB) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for `a+b+b`, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
   θ                Input string
  Ｅ                 Map over characters
      θ             Input string
     ⮌              Reversed
    …               Truncated to length
       κ            Current index
 Φ                  Filtered where
        ι           Reversed suffix (is not empty)
⊙                   Any reversed suffix satisfies
              ι     Current reversed suffix
             ∕ ²    First half
           ×²       Repeated twice
         ⁼          Equals
          ι         Current reversed suffix
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 6 bytes

```
Ḣᶜϩ½≈a
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLhuKLhtpzPqcK94omIYSIsIiIsIlNOWVlZIiwiMy40LjEiXQ==)

Essentially, a case is truthy if some suffix of the input minus the first character (ensuring a is non empty) can be split into two equal halves.

### Explained

```
Ḣᶜϩ½≈a­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Ḣ       # ‎⁡Remove the first character of the string because it could be `a`
 ᶜϩ     # ‎⁢Over all suffixes:
   ½    # ‎⁣  Split into halves
    ≈   # ‎⁤  And test whether both halves are the same
     a  # ‎⁢⁡Output whether any are true.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @NahuelFouilleul*

```perl
$_=/.(.+)\1$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZfT0NPWzPGUEX//383R5/gyBDX4BBnx2DXYC5UbgReWTTJYF/HoBBPV0cg5goOBvL9IiMjwSSQgJCRfpH/8gtKMvPziv/rFuQAAA)

Comment: [-2 bytes Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZfT0NPWzPGUEX//383R5/gyBDX4BBnx2DXYC5UbgReWTTJYF/HoBBPV0cg5goOBvL9IiMjwSSQgJCRfpH/8gtKMvPziv/rFuQAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") because a non-empty string before is enough

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)*

```
ba₁ḍ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/PynxUVPjwx29tv//Kzk5OkUCkRIA)

#### Explanation

```
b      Remove the first character from the input
 a₁    Get a nonempty suffix of the remaining string
   ḍ   Split it into two halves
    =  Assert that both are identical
```

The first `b` is necessary to prevent the prefix from being empty.

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8T0p81NT4cEevbfL//9FKwcHBSjpKwX6RkZFQGkzB6Eg/EO3m6BMcGeIaHOLsGOwajCEQQUAeQzrY1zEoxNPVEYiVYgE) by removing a non-empty prefix ahead of time :P

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks. (That's -2 bytes, actually.)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN (CBQN)](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 42 bytes

```
{∨´(≡˝2‿↑⊸⥊)¨2↓»↓}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704qTBvwdK0R20TqpeWlqTpWtzUqn7UseLQFo1HnQtPzzV61LD_UdvER107Hi3t0jy0wuhR2-RDu4HEh7lTV9ZCdGyq5XrUsCg4I79cwU1BKdgvMlIJIrFgAYQGAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Three different alternatives:

- `.œ3ùε¦Ë}à` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//y7FkzPDuc61wqbDi33DoP//U05ZWVk) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf72jk40P7zy39dCyw921hxf81/kfHBzMFewXGRkJJoEEhIz0i@Ryc/QJjgxxDQ5xdgx2DYZw0cVCnCMinUEUEHEF@zoGhXi6OgIxAA).
- `.s¨ε2äË}à` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fr/jQinNbjQ4vOdxde3jB///BfpGRkQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf73iQyvObTU6vORwd@3hBf91/gcHB3MF@0VGRoJJIAEhI/0iudwcfYIjQ1yDQ5wdg12DIVxsYnBuBF5ZNMlgX8egEE9XRyAGAA).
- `¦D.s2×Å¿à` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0DIXvWKjw9MPtx7af3jB///BfpGRkQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/0PLXPSKjQ5PP9x6aP/hBf91/gcHB3MF@0VGRoJJIAEhI/0iudwcfYIjQ1yDQ5wdg12DIVxsYnBuBF5ZNMlgX8egEE9XRyAGAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ        # Get all partitions of the (implicit) input-string
  3ù      # Only keep the partitions containing three parts
    ε     # Map over each over each remaining partition:
     ¦    #  Remove the first part
      Ë   #  Check if the remaining two parts are equal
    }à    # After the map: check if any is truthy
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
.s        # Get all suffixes of the (implicit) input-string
  ¨       # Remove the last suffix (the input itself)
   ε      # Map over each suffix:
    2ä    #  Split it into two equal-sized parts (first part is larger for odd lengths)
      Ë   #  Check that both parts are equal
   }à     # After the map: check if any is truthy
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
¦         # Remove the first character of the (implicit) input-string
 D        # Duplicate it
  .s      # Pop the copy, and push its prefixes
    2×    # Double each string
      Å¿  # Check if the input minus first character ends with a string
        à # Check if any is truthy
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with regex, <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```python
import re
f=re.compile(r'.+(.+)\1$').match
```

Python3 port of the Javascript answer.

Takes a string for input, returns a `re.Match` object as truthy, `None` as falsy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY4xC8IwEIX3/IoQhCZUAuImOBRpQdAOJoMBlxJSGmibkMShvz5qq120OBz3eHf3vbNDaEy/jVF31rgAnQL13ikqTWd1q7BLaIppSm6bVUJoVwXZROt0HzDi7i4HGJQPHhFQGwdl5RXUPcSIMYbWELFSCPERU5@FKAUiOwAnWo1fx4QA8KYXVeuX6EV2YoLnjB8ylo9Bo7Ngz87138L3nJ2zCz/m2bN@PBsf)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>65</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```python
lambda s:any(s.endswith(2*s[i:],1)for i in range(len(s)))
```

Takes a string for input, returns `True` and `False` accordingly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU6xDoIwEN35iqZTa4iJupE4FAOJiTJYBht1qFCkCRbC1Ri@HgWURY3D5d69e@/dVY3NS7Nos@WxLeT1nEoEnjQNgakyKdy1zcl8AgftndwZzcoaaaQNqqW5KFIoQ4BS2la1NpbguL4lDbIKLGDqdOJEgur0BHPOsYswj4QQbzD0EYhIYOo5aEjLSGem1HFe6aEs4Fd6yDZcxAGPV4wH/aGe@UGPzP6f4HPPt2wXrwP2rG5kvs/8L1@3Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```scala
s=>".+(.+)\\1$".r.findFirstIn(s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVHRasIwFGWvfsUl7CHBWRh7GUILZVQQ1IHpYEV9iDXVbF1akrghwy_Ziy_zZV_kvmZp6yrixmAP4d6cnHPPueRtq2OWsquPEWrJ7IUpiSY7nU0feGygz4SE1wbAjCfwZC-Yqblug68UW42oUULOJ6QNd1IYcC3TUgGeWQrxgsePQ55zZviMLqe65LZxpXG929yITNYjrPh9aZLW9Q606yGniZ0mGY8vz5GjnETIWUcobboSa1LxPs82pVdu9SaVGIVqGa_AcG00InUMU6BhAVqHntAGI0opugBEB1EUfTdVrZtoEO1nHPROkinO4gUuLMD1auefNy1phJDGccoOS_VpyqRAj1N2_B6NwoCGNz4NysAl8gtcI_d_EU7fad8fht3At2cf6RDnv0sDrBvr6qM2m6p-AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 39 bytes

Prompts for string.

```
×+/n=+/¨(n↑¨⊂v)=n↑¨(n←⍳⌊.5×⍴v)↓¨⊂v←⌽1↓⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/@Hp2vp5ttr6h1Zo5D1qm3hoxaOupjJNWwgbJDThUe/mRz1deqaHpz/q3VKm@ahtMkQRSKpnryGQDzTyP9Awrv9pXOrBwcHqXCDaLzIyEs6CMhCsSD8Iy83RJzgyxDU4xNkx2DUYi1AEQRVYFAT7OgaFeLo6ArG6AgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 90 bytes

The function takes as input a string `s`. It returns `0` for True cases, `None` for False ones.

```python
def f(s):
 l=len(s)
 for i in range(1,l):
  x=(i+l)//2
  if s[i:x]==s[x:]:return 0
 return
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHBa4MwGMXv@Su@m7oJtfYyBA9ZsTDYelg8KOLBbdEGQpQkMvvXu6izTaGMHQLvve9HePnSnfWpFbunTo7jF62hdpUXIeAxp8JIBHUrgQETICvRUHfr82kOQ@yyR@5tNqExrAZVsGgo41gVQ1RGkupeCggQLGrUstenM8RQGBzAIYQ4/q885nlum6u@MflxMiVCdcWVddUBv5I8TUi6xyS53Dqnf4wuafYf6D5D3vB7@pJgc5ZmgjbXXlm2crz9pvKzUnQNtuFulfh57zyEQRAsTzPLVtOyl31FM9NJJrSbyp768/d4FjfvwsYOJrjDmWY25RjPWcM@uOm0wOMP)

---

*Explanation*

The function takes as input a string `s`.

The `i` loop takes substrings of `s` representing `b+b`, starting from the second character in order to leave a non-empty substring `a`.

`x` represents the middle of the substring.

The two halves of the substring are compared: if they are equal, return `0`. If no equal halves are found, return `None`.

Comment: Surely you can use regex...

Comment: @Sny Smartie I know, but I don't know them very well!

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 57 bytes

```bash
repeat $#1-2 {1=${1:1};eval '>${1//${1:0:'{2..$#1}'-1}}'}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwc1paflFCoYKGsHBwVzBfpGRkWASSEDISL9ILjdHn-DIENfgEGfHYNdgCBebGJwbgVcWTTLY1zEoxNPVEYg1uao1uIpTSxR0U5eWlqTpWty0LEotSE0sUVBRNtQ1Uqg2tFWpNrQyrLVOLUvMUVC3A_L09UFCBlbq1UZ6ekBlteq6hrW16rUQAzZoWqcmZ-QrqNhbKxTlKmhBhRcsgNAA)

Outputs via exit code.